# Firebase Chrome Extension Javascript content_security_policy Manifest 3

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, content-security-policy

I just started working with `chrome extensions` and `javascript` and saw that everyone suggests to use `Manifest version 3` to start off. I wanted to implement `firebase` into my extension and in the old `Manifest version 2` i needed to put in this:

```
"content_security_policy": "script-src 'self' https://cdn.firebase.com https://apis.google.com https://www.gstatic.com; object-src 'self'"
```

to make everything work. But this section has changed now in `Manifest version 3`. Its supposed to look similar to this:

```
"content_security_policy": {
    "extension_pages": "...",
    "sandbox": "..."
  },
```

but i can not make it work :/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This tuto [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UjH2INUPmF4&ab_channel=RustyZone) to may help you. It worked for me.