# Chrome Extension - how do I get the window object in Manifest Version 3 (MV3)?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, manifest.json

**Overview**

I was able to successfully inject my Javascript script through the new [`chrome.scripting` API](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/mv3/content_scripts/).

However, I am still unable to access the page's `window` object via this injected script.

**What I have tried**

Back in MV2 I used to do the following:

```
async function getWindow() {
    return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
      const script = document.createElement('script');
      script.text = `
            const _window = JSON.stringify(window);
            document.body.insertAdjacentHTML("beforebegin", "<div id='dummy' style='display:none;width:0;height:0;pointer-events:none;'>"+_window+"</div>")
        `;

      document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(script);

      const _window = document.getElementById('dummy');
      const data = JSON.parse(_window.innerText)

      script.remove();
      resolve(data);
    });
  }

 (async () => {
    const _window = await getWindow();
    console.log(_window)
  })();
```

But it's no longer possible. it gives me the following error:

> Refused to execute inline script because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "script-src 'self'". Either the 'unsafe-inline' keyword, a hash ('sha256-iAKY8pCLpBsSPttuizEMbuFVrucrXcGUoo/RYdGQEyw='), or a nonce ('nonce-...') is required to enable inline execution.

Based on that error I found [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52498189/4781067) and [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65586455/firebase-chrome-extension-javascript-content-security-policy-manifest-3) answer, but it doesn't solve my problem since the former is for the MV2 and the latter is using an external script. I can't seen to make it work with a local script.

**What I'm trying to achieve**

I would like to access the `window` object of a given website from my Chrome Extension.

**Other notes**

- In my manifest I have the following permissions:

```
  "permissions": ["scripting", "activeTab", "webRequest"]
```

Additionally, I have added my script under `content_scripts` and also `web_accessible_resources`.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Thank you!

Comment: 1) Use a separate js file for the script element, 2) JSON.stringify(window) will fail due to circular references. 3) Example: [Access global js variables from js injected by a chrome extension](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46870005)